# FMT - How to parse fmt format string for floating point format arguments?

Tags: c++, fmt

I want to use a custom decimal number type with fmt.  The decimal type generates an output string using it's own method.  I am failing to understand how to parse the context string beyond single chars, to get numeric precision, etc.  Which I can then send to the string method, to generate the relevant output, that then gets passed to a string formatter when returning the result.  The custom type does not contain native floating type to directly format.  Converting to a native type also doesn't work, as the decimal may have greater exponent, or precision than a native type.

Per the documentation I am not certain this is possible.  Or I am not going in the right direction.

Thank in advance for any clarifications!

```
template<>
    struct std::formatter<Number> {

        Format_Args fmt;

        constexpr auto parse(std::format_parse_context& context) {

            auto it = context.begin();
            auto end = context.end();

            if (it != end && (*it == 'f' || *it == 'e')) {
                fmt.type = *it++;
            }

            return it;
        }

        template<typename Context>
        constexpr auto format(const Number n, Context& context) {

            return formatter<std::string>::format(n.to_string(fmt), context);
        }
    };
```

I looked at the API documentation, without success.  Also looked through the fmt tagged posts, looking for an answer.  This [post](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), comes close to what I am looking for.  But doesn't comment on how to parse for multiple arguments, or variable arguments.

Comment: Are you using `fmt` external library or `format` form standard library available since C++20?

Comment: "This post" points to stackoverflow home page :) Please provide correct link.

Comment: Does the code you posted works? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] which will show your problem exactly. You can start with something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/rs77c658W Note that support of `std::format` requires some specific compiler version (for example gcc +13), since C++20 support is still under development, so problem might be tools used.

Comment: @Marek R, and @KamilCuk, yes the code works just fine, the problem is I was unable to figure out how to capture the entire text string parsed by the formatter, regardless if I used `fmt` or the `std` library.  This was due to a lack of understanding how `constexpr` work during compile time by myself.  I do appreciate you both taking a look at the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out after reading this [tutorial](https://www.cppstories.com/2022/custom-stdformat-cpp20/).  While it did not directly answer my question.  It did allow me to figure out a way to capture all of the text format sent for context.

Then  I can parse it as needed in the format method.  Below is a simple example of how to capture the parsed text to a vector, to be processed later.  In this can simply outputting them to the std:ostream output.

```cpp
namespace std {

    struct Color {
        uint8_t r{ 0 };
        uint8_t g{ 0 };
        uint8_t b{ 0 };
    };

    template <>
    struct std::formatter<Color> {

        std::vector<char> context;

        constexpr auto parse(std::format_parse_context& ctx) {

            auto pos = ctx.begin();

            while (pos != ctx.end() && *pos != '}') {
                
                context.push_back(*pos);
                
                ++pos;
            }
            return pos;  // This must be '}'.
        }

        auto format(const Color& col, std::format_context& ctx) {

            bool hex = false;

            for (auto c : context) {
                std::cout << c;

                if (c == '!') {
                    std::cout << "\n";
                }
                
                if (c == 'h' || c == 'H') {
                    hex = true;
                }
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;

            if (hex) {
                uint32_t val = col.r << 16 | col.g << 8 | col.b;
                return std::format_to(ctx.out(), "#{:x}", val);
            }

            return std::format_to(ctx.out(), "({}, {}, {})", col.r, col.g, col.b);
        }
    };
}

int main() {

    Color a;

    std::cout << std::format("{:Hello formatter!.50}", a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Resulting in this output:

```cpp
Hello formatter!
.50
#0
```

Below is the updated formatter that compiles passing the parsed arguments to my object class.  Note that all the parsing happens at compile time.

```cpp
namespace std {

    template <>
    struct std::formatter<Number> : std::formatter<std::string> {
        /*
            In the base Decimal class is a format struct, to capture the relevant data.
            It is defaulted to the argument values below.

            struct Format_Args {
                char sign  = '-';
                char align = '<';
                int  width = -1;
                int  prec  = -1;
                char type  = 'd';
                int  base  = 10;
                char fill  = ' ';
                char pref  = '\0';
                bool pad   = false;
                bool local = false;
            };
        */

        Decimal::Format_Args fmt;

        constexpr auto parse(std::format_parse_context& ctx) {

            bool padding_not_set = true;

            bool prec_definition = false;

            int arg_buffer = 0;

            auto pos = ctx.begin();

            char last_c = ' ';
            char c      = ' ';

            while (pos != ctx.end() && *pos != '}') {

                last_c = c;
                c      = *pos;

                switch (c) {

                case '<':
                case '^':
                case '>':
                    fmt.align = c;
                    fmt.fill  = last_c;
                    break;

                case '+':
                case '-':
                case ' ':
                    fmt.sign = c;
                    break;

                case '#':
                    fmt.pref = c;
                    break;

                case '0':
                    if (padding_not_set) {
                        fmt.pad = true;
                        padding_not_set = !padding_not_set;
                    }
                    arg_buffer *= 10;
                    break;

                case '.':
                    prec_definition = true;
                    fmt.width  = arg_buffer / 10;
                    arg_buffer = 0;
                    break;

                case 'L':
                    fmt.local = true;
                    break;

                case 'b':
                case 'B':
                    fmt.type = c;
                    fmt.base = 2;
                    break;
                case 'o':
                case 'O':
                    fmt.type = c;
                    fmt.base = 8;
                    break;
                case 'x':
                case 'X':
                    fmt.type = c;
                    fmt.base = 16;
                    break;

                case 'd':
                case 'D':
                case 'g':
                case 'G':
                    fmt.type = c;
                    fmt.base = 10;
                    break;
                case 'e':
                case 'E':
                case 'f':
                case 'F':
                    fmt.type = c;
                    fmt.base = 0;
                    break;

                case '1':
                case '2':
                case '3':
                case '4':
                case '5':
                case '6':
                case '7':
                case '8':
                case '9':
                    arg_buffer += c - '0';
                    arg_buffer *= 10;
                    padding_not_set = false;
                    break;
                }
                
                ++pos;
            }

            if (fmt.pref == '#') {
                fmt.pref = fmt.type;
            }

            if (prec_definition) {
                fmt.prec = arg_buffer / 10;
            }
            else {
                fmt.width = arg_buffer / 10;
            }

            return pos;
        }

        auto format(const Number& a, std::format_context& ctx) {

            return std::format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", a.to_string(fmt));
        }
    };
}
```